# Filtering a list of uniform lists

Tags: haskell

I've been attempting to find a solution to this problem for a couple of days now and before getting too frustrated with myself I decided to ask for help.

I have a list of uniform lists, e.g. `[[2], [2, 2], [3], [3, 3] [3, 3, 3], [5]]` and I want to apply a filter so that only the lists which aren't subsets of any of the rest of the lists remain.

That was a complicated sentence. Basically I need a function `f` for which

```
f [[2], [2, 2], [3], [3, 3] [3, 3, 3], [5]]
```

results in

```
[[2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [5]]
```

I hope I've made myself clear. If not, help me clarify!

Comment: has it to be a prefix or a subset? (so is `[2,3]` a subset of `[3,3,2]` in your sense or not?)

Comment: also: your samples are all mutliple instances of the same value - can we use this property or is it happenstance?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, that's not the most efficient way to store those data. What's the context?

Comment: Yes, the lists will always be multiple instances of the same value, rendering your first question irrelevant to the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want this:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

f :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
f = map (maximumBy (compare `on` length)) . groupBy ((==) `on` head) . sortBy (compare `on` head)
```

We just group the lists together by their head and select the maximum of each.

If I did not understand you wrong, you want to select the list which is not a sublist of the other lists, which is essentially the longest list for each group.

Comment: You should add that this assumes the list is sorted.

Comment: @mateogianolio I'll add it in a sec

Comment: Oh, and ```(Eq a)``` should now be ```(Ord a)```.

Comment: `head` is cheap, but `length` is costly. Probably better to [decorate-transform-undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) the stuff, in the last step.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your lists are all uniform, in that no list contains two different elements (i.e. `[2, 3]`), you could instead pose this question in terms of length:

```
> import Control.Arrow
> -- Equivalent to `\x -> (head x, length x)`
> :t head &&& length
head &&& length :: [a] -> (a, Int)
> (head &&& length) [2, 2, 2]
(2, 3)
>
> let myData = <what you have above>
> map (head &&& length) myData
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 3), (5, 1)]
```

Now you can group by the first element

```
> import Data.List
> :t groupBy
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
> import Data.Function
> :t on
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
> :t on (==) fst
on (==) fst :: Eq b => (b, b1) -> (b, b1) -> Bool
> :t groupBy (on (==) fst)
groupBy (on (==) fst) :: Eq b -> [(b, b1)] -> [[(b, b1)]]
> groupBy (on (==) fst) $ map (head &&& length) myData
[[(2,1),(2,2)],[(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)],[(5,1)]]
```

Then you can select the term with largest `snd`:

```
> :t maximumBy
maximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
> import Data.Ord
> :t comparing
comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
> :t comparing snd
comparing snd :: Ord a => (a1, a) -> (a1, a) -> Ordering
> :t maximumBy (comparing snd)
maximumBy (comparing snd) :: Ord a -> [(a1, a)] -> (a1, a)
> :t map (maximumBy (comparing snd))
map (maximumBy (comparing snd)) :: Ord a => [[(a1, a)]] -> [(a1, a)]
> map (maximumBy (comparing snd)) $ groupBy (on (==) fst) $ map (head &&& length) myData
[(2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 1)]
```

And now, if you want, you can convert it back to lists using `replicate`:

```
> map (uncurry (flip replicate)) $ map (maximumBy (comparing snd)) $ groupBy (on (==) fst) $ map (head &&& length) myData
[[2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [5]]
```

---

The final function would look like

```
import Data.List (groupBy, maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Function (on)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

biggestUnique :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
biggestUnique
    = map     (uncurry   (flip replicate))   -- Convert back to lists
    . map     (maximumBy (comparing snd))    -- Select by the maximum length
    . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)                -- Group by the element value
    . map     (head &&&  length)             -- Reformulate in terms of length
```

And you could compress the `map`s into one, but I think it makes it less readable.

WARNING: This won't work properly where your elements aren't unique in each sublist.

Answer (score 1):

No list is a proper sublist of the empty list. The empty list is a proper sublist of every non-empty list.

```
import Data.List (delete)

sublist :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
sublist _        []               = False
sublist []       _                = True
sublist (x : xs) ys | x `elem` ys = sublist xs (delete x ys)
                    | otherwise   = False
```

With `none pred  =  not . any pred`, and without an `Ord` constraint:

```
superlists :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
superlists xss = filter (\ xs -> none (xs `sublist`) xss) xss
```

meaning

```
superlists [[1,2,2],[2,2,1],[1],[]]  ==  [[1,2,2],[2,2,1]]
```

and

```
superlists [[2],[2,2],[3],[3,3],[3,3,3],[5]]  ==  [[2,2],[3,3,3],[5]]
```

---

Denotationally equivalent alternative `sublist`:

```
elemDelete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> (Bool, [a])
elemDelete _ []                   = (False, [])
elemDelete y (x : xs) | x == y    = (True, xs)
                      | otherwise = let (b, zs) = elemDelete y xs
                                    in  (b, x : zs)

sublist :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
sublist _        [] = False
sublist []       _  = True
sublist (x : xs) ys = let (b, dys) = elemDelete x ys
                      in  if b then sublist xs dys 
                               else False
```

But `elemDelete y xs` is actually less efficient than `(elem y xs, delete y xs)`.